# how to make element dragable after completion of it's animation in java script or css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, css-animations

I animated the element using this code

```
#h1
{
position: absolute;
animation: diagonal_h1 2s;
animation-play-state: paused;
animation-fill-mode forwards;
}

@keyframes diagonal_h1
{
    0%       { transform: translatex(0px) translatey(0px) }
    100%     { transform: translatex(-50px) translatey(-100px) }
}
```

I am playing the animation using a button.
But when I try to make it dragable by (interactive.js library)

```
const position = { x: 0, y: 0 }

interact('#h1').draggable({
  listeners: {
    start (event) {
      console.log(event.type, event.target)
    },
    move (event) {
      position.x += event.dx
      position.y += event.dy

      event.target.style.transform =
        `translate(${position.x}px, ${position.y}px)`
    },
  }
})
```

The element is not moving by draging. So I Removed the `animation-fill-mode forwards;`

By doing this the the element is dragable but **the problem is the element does not stay on its final state**

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

While the element still has that animation set then it will maintain its fill-mode-forward transformed state.

To solve this you can remove the animation just before you want to transform the element on the user dragging.

Here is a simple snippet - not using a library - which has one element animating, then with its position translated after a few seconds without removing the animation and a second element animating and with its position translated the same after a few seconds but with the animation removed.

You will see the first element changes color but does not move, the second one moves after a few seconds.

```js
const first = document.querySelector('.first');
const second = document.querySelector('.second');
setTimeout(function() {
  first.style.transform = 'translate(50px, 0)';
  first.style.color = 'red';
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function() {
  second.style.animation = 'none';
  second.style.transform = 'translate(50px, 0)';
  second.style.color = 'blue';
}, 5000);
```

```css
.move {
  animation: move 1s linear 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
  100% {
    transform: translate(50px, 50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="move first">FIRST ELEMENT</div>
<div class="move second">SECOND ELEMENT</div>
```